# Is one allowed to short sell stock?

Tags: halacha, business, lending-interest-ribbis

Short selling stock involves borrowing the shares for a fee. Would doing so contravene Devarim 23:20 which prohibits borrowing with interest (assume the Jewishness of all parties involved is such to warrant problems of interest)? What is the halacha on this?

Comment: Answer: http://traditionarchive.org/news/_pdfs/0056-0077.pdf

Comment: Fascinating question! Ultimately this can be asked not just on stocks but on anything that’s not technically money but is used as such; is it Ribbis to rent your credit card, for instance.